# I'm having trouble getting values from ajax code

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

In my application, I want to read data that return from the ajax code.
Until now I have created when user click the table data row, it's **Id** will get from the jQuery and pass it to a Ajax code and from the action it will returns data with 2 columns.

Now here I want to know that from the returned data, how I can read or assign first columns to one variable and other to another variable.

I tried to check by putting alert and return I get alert as **object Object**

I'm not an expert with the Ajax code, still learning and need to know how this should be done.

This is my code.

```
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#tblParts tr").click(function (event) {
       var cell = this.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
       var CellId = cell.innerText;
       IsSelected(CellId);
   });
   
   $("#tblUnParts tr").click(function (event) {
       var cell = this.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
       var CellId = cell.innerText;
       IsSelected(CellId);
   });
   
   function IsSelected(id) {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '../Home/GetData',
           data: '{ Id:"' + id + '" }',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {
               if (data.Success == true) {
                   var inventoryMovement = data.MovementInventory;
                   alert(inventoryMovement);
                  
               }
           }
       });
   }
</script>
```

Here is the controller

```
public ActionResult GetData(int Id)
{
  var Movement = db.InventoryMovement.Where(x => x.PartNo_Id ==Id).ToList();
  return Json(new { Success = true, MovementInventory = Movement });
}
```

Comment: try alert(JSON.stringify(inventoryMovement)); it will help you to identify the response.

Comment: @Som Thanks. I got the data I wanted

Comment: Always better to use `console.log` as alert() is truncated, converted to a string (hence `[object Object]`) and transitory.  But ok for a first step.

Comment: *I got the data I wanted* - so your question is resolved?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue has been resolved in the comments.